# why does not implementing equals method in Java cause memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I am trying to understand various reasons for memory leak one of the samples i saw where hashCode() was implemented and not equals(). I have read through that one if one is over ridden the other also has to be over ridden because of contract violation.

this is the sample code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MemoryLeak {

static class Key { 
    Integer id; 

    Key(Integer id) { 
        this.id = id; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public int hashCode() { 
        return id.hashCode(); 
    }   
} 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Map m = new HashMap(); 
    while (true) 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
            if (!m.containsKey(i)) 
                m.put(new Key(i), "Number:" + i); 
}
}
```

I know i have not implemented the equals() method on purpose. But i want to under stand why is memory leak is created what is going on internally.

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't implement `Key#equals()`, no two `Key` instances will be equal, so `Map#containsKey()` will always return `false`. Additionally, you're checking `containsKey(i)`, but **not using `i` as a key.** Even if you did implement `Key#equals()`, that `containsKey` check is effectively `if(true)`.

Consequently, this code unconditionally adds logically-distinct entries to the map, so its size grows without bound.